# Creating nested schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Suppose I have this Mongoose Schema in my `models.js` file:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProjectSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    "name": String,
    "id": String,
    "phone": String,
    "address": String,
    "dob": String,
    "action": String, 
    "ccard": { 
        "type": String,
        "number": String,
        "status": String,
        "expiry": String
    }
});

exports.Project = Mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

And suppose I already have website that uses MongoDB to load data from a JSON file with the necessary information. How would I call `ccard`'s fields in a HTML template? As of now I'm able to call `{{name}}` and `{{id}}` in the  `{{each projects}} ... {{/each}}` clause without issues, but when I call `{{ccard.number}}` it would not output anything.

HTML sample:

```
{{each projects}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ccard.type}}</td>
        <td>{{ccard.number}}</td>
        <td>{{ccard.status}}</td>
        <td>{{ccard.expiry}}</td>                                                  
    </tr>
</table>
{{/each}}
```

Is the problem in the schema or the template variables or somewhere else?

Comment: have you tried `{{ccard.type}}` in your template?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all of `ccard`'s member variables, but none of the data in the JSON that corresponds to those variables appear when I run the site.

Comment: Can you add the HTML template code to the question. Where is `digits` field in ProjectSchema?

Comment: @Mahesh my bad, that is `number` but I wrote it as `digits`. I will correct it. I will add the HTML template code.

Comment: If you are using windows (I don´t know if there is a linux version) you can use MongoVue to see if data is saved (it is similar at phpmyadmin... more or less).

Comment: @maregor do you have the data in the DB?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin check my answer. "type" might be the issue

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin the data is stored in mongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProjectSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    "name": String,
    "id": String,
    "phone": String,
    "address": String,
    "dob": String,
    "action": String, 
    "ccard": { 
        "type": {
            "type": String,
        }
        "number": String,
        "status": String,
        "expiry": String
    }
});

exports.Project = Mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

I am not sure whether above code works. If it doesn't change the column name as mentioned below.

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProjectSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    "name": String,
    "id": String,
    "phone": String,
    "address": String,
    "dob": String,
    "action": String, 
    "ccard": { 
        "ccartType": String,
        "number": String,
        "status": String,
        "expiry": String
    }
});

exports.Project = Mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Your template code

```
{{each projects}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ccard.ccartType}}</td>
        <td>{{ccard.number}}</td>
        <td>{{ccard.status}}</td>
        <td>{{ccard.expiry}}</td>                                                  
    </tr>
</table>
{{/each}}
```

Change the model as mentioned above and make sure the model is changed in the mongodb schema.

Reason might be it is taking `ccard` as a single column with `type`:`string`

Answer (score 2):

Schema is written correctly.
I can see

```
"ccard": { 
      "type": String,
      "number": String,
      "status": String,
      "expiry": String
}
```

you can access by your variable name in which document is saved. Let assume you fetched 1 document in

```
var = project
```

now you can access `#{project.ccard.status}` or `{{project.ccard.status}}`

Comment: @Trisha I don't think schema is correct `ccard` type is set as string.

Comment: @Mahesh all I did was format the code of the original answer - maybe yojnajaininfo can shed some more light on the answer?